# Laravel / Lumen limit 1 in join closure

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, lumen, eloquent

I try to retrieve some data from a table but I need only one item.

Tables:
reservations, reservation_products, products_price_history.

The table structure is too complex so let's use only what we need:

reservations:

```
| id | date       |
-------------------
| 1  | 2017-10-03 |
```

reservation_products

```
| id | reservation_id |
-----------------------
| 1  | 1              |
```

products_price_history

```
| id | product_id | start_date | end_date   | price |
-----------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 2017-09-20 | 2017-10-01 | 200   |
| 2  | 1          | 2017-10-01 | NULL       | 200   |
```

A reservation has many prouducts and a product have many prices. I need to take the price that it's start_date is less than reservation's date.

THe logic:

```
$users = User::with(['reservations' => function($query) {

    // reservation products
    $query->with(['reservation_products' => function($query) {
        $query->join('reservations', 'reservation_products.reservation_id', 'reservations.id');
        $query->join('products', 'reservation_products.product_id', 'products.id');

        $query->join('products_price_history', function($query) {
            $query->on('reservations.salon_id', 'products_price_history.salon_id');
            $query->on('reservation_products.product_id', 'products_price_history.product_id');
            $query->on('reservation_products.product_type_id', 'products_price_history.product_type_id');
            $query->whereRaw('reservations.date >= products_price_history.date_start');
            $query->limit(1);
        });
    }]);

}])->get();
```

The `$query->limit(1);` is not working. The query just gives me all the entries that are lower than reservations date.

Thanks.

Comment: I’d forget about the laravel stuff for now and instead see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: then use `whereBetween` clause instead